# Problemas a renderizar en PrimeFaces

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, primefaces

Estoy intentando renderizar un pop up en una página jsp, pero este no aparece ni da error. Intento debuguear pero ni entra el programa. Inspecciono con el f12 e igual no aparece en el DOM. Lo que he hecho ha sido una subview en un archivo jsp. Este lo controlo desde el JS. Y a la vez lo metro en el controlador del archivo java, donde lo renderizo y meto el nuevo método.

Dejo el código:

Página JSP

```
 <ui:tableColumn id="baixaAppColumn" sort="baixaApp" binding="#{pages$RSAApplication.baixaAplicacio}" >
 <ui:imageHyperlink id="idBaixaAppSobre" rendered="#{pages$RSAApplication.rolSEGGAP}"> </ui:imageHyperlink>
</ui:tableColumn>
```

Controlador Java

```
    public ImageHyperlink baixaAplicacio = new ImageHyperlink();
    public ImageHyperlink getBaixaAplicacio () {
        return baixaAplicacio;
    }
    public void setBaixaAplicacio(ImageHyperlink baixaAplicacio) {
        this.baixaAplicacio = baixaAplicacio;
    }
    
    private ImageHyperlink createIconaBaixaApp() {
        ImageHyperlink iconaBaixaApp = new ImageHyperlink();
        String text = getText("rsaApplication.novaNotificacio");
        
        iconaBaixaApp.setImageURL("/images/delete.gif");
        iconaBaixaApp.setAlt(text);
        iconaBaixaApp.setToolTip(text);
        iconaBaixaApp.setOnClick("showNavigationPopUp(); window.scroll(0,0); initBaixaAplicacio(); doCustomPopUpBaixaAplicacio('executeCreateBaixaAplicacio'); return false;");
        iconaBaixaApp.setTarget("");
        
        return iconaBaixaApp;
    }
```

Método en JS

```
function initBaixaAplicacio() {
    var codiApp = document.getElementById('form:BaixaAppSubview:codiBaixaAplicacio');
    codiApp.value = ""; 
    var nomApp = document.getElementById('form:BaixaAppSubview:nomBaixaAplicacio');
    nomApp.value = ""; 
    var dataBaixaApp = document.getElementById('form:BaixaAppSubview:dataBaixaAplicacio');
    dataBaixaApp.value = ""; 
}
```